# jQuery expanding and sliding boxes

Tags: jquery, user-experience

Having trouble animating the expanding of the row, and sliding of the row.

```
<div>       
    <div>
        <h2><a href="#laptops" class="exp">Laptops</a></h2>
        <p>Laptops...</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h2><a href="#tablets" class="exp">Tablets</a></h2>
        <p>Tablets...</p>

    </div>
    <!--the row below is the one that will expand and move left/right -->       
    <div id="row1" class="expand intro_para">
        <div id="laptops" class="expand block">
            PAGE FOR Laptops this includes a lot of info
        </div>

        <div id="tablets" class="expand block">
            Page for tablets  this also includes a lot of info
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Looks like:

[image: Picture of interface]

Initially the highlighted row would be closed, then open when one of the categories is selected. If the category is already expanded, it will close the row, if the other category is selected, it will slide open to the new category. **I think I have it about done but it will not show the new category when the row is slid over.**
Note: the highlighted box is the only thing that will be affected.

Think of it like a navigation at the top of the page, but instead of hover you have to click  and there will be animation between the switching of the menus.

When the category anchor is clicked it will run this function:

```
function show(cat) {
console.log("B4side_open"+side_open+"row_open"+row_open+"cat_open"+cat_open);
var tcat = _.where(equipment, {title: cat});
var s = tcat[0].side;
var r = tcat[0].row;
//no row open

if(row_open == "") {
//open row to specified cat
    console.log("open row "+r+" to specified cat "+cat);
    //make category visible (within invisible box)
    $("#"+cat).css({"display": "block"});
    //open the row
    $("#row"+r).slideDown();
    row_open = r;
    side_open = s;
    cat_open = cat;
}
else {
//slide the expando to new cat OR close the exando
    if(s == side_open) {
        //close the expando
        console.log("close the expando for row "+r);
        //close the row
        $("#row"+r).slideUp();
        //make the category invisible (within invisible box)
        //$("#"+cat).css({"display": "none"});
        row_open = "";
        side_open = "";
        cat_open = "";
    }
    else {
        //slide the expando
        if (s == "left") {
            //slide right
            console.log("slide right");
            $("#"+cat).css({"display": "block"});
            $("#row"+r).animate({"margin-left": "0px"}, 1000);
            //make other invisible
        }
        if (s == "right") {
            //slide left
            console.log("slide left");
            console.log(cat+r)
            $("#"+cat).css({"display": "block"});

            //console.log($("#"+cat).css({"display": "block"}));
            $("#row"+r).animate({"margin-left": "-940px"}, 1000);
        }
        //make the category invisible (within invisible box)
        //$("#"+cat).css({"display": "none"});
        side_open = s;
        cat_open = cat;
    }
}
}
```

UPDATE:: Ive been working on it, I think its about done right, but the initial opening and sliding, it will jump open and not animate :/

http://mulibraries.missouri.edu/reference/equipment/equipment.php

Comment: are there only 2 categories, or will there be more than 2?

Comment: there are more, they will be shown underneath in 2 columns (see the link above)

Comment: Odds are that for anything library related, someone's already got something to use as a starting point.  If you want to ask about the whole thing (and not just a specific feature you're trying to implement), you may want to ask at [code4lib](https://listserv.nd.edu/cgi-bin/wa?SUBED1=CODE4LIB&A=1)

Comment: Thanks! I'm basing the overall look off of [NC State](http://www.lib.ncsu.edu/techlending), their library is well funded and they have a lot of good stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed it, it was a css issue where the row was supposed to be display:none and the inner categories were supposed to be display:block

Answer (score 1):

You need to get

```
if (s == "left") {}
if (s == "right") {}
```

Inside

```
if(row_open == "") {}
```

Answer (score 1):

by broadening your selectors and making some other changes, you should be able to eliminate the vast majority of your code. Take a look at this:

```
$("a.exp").click(function () {
  var foo = $(this.hash);     

  var leftColumn = $(".expand .block").index(foo) % 2 == 0;
  var animateOut =  { "margin-left": "-924px" };
  var animateIn =  { "margin-left": "0px" }; 
  $(".expand .block").slideUp(400, function() { $(this).animate(animateOut);});
  foo.slideDown(400, function() { foo.animate(animateIn);});
  return false;
});
```

Comment: forgot to mention that as you discovered, you need to have at least the `row1`XX divs at display:block

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try tommorrow, right now its working fine :)